# How to add custom options while adding product to the wishlist

Tags: magento

I want to add the custom options to the product when i add the product to the wishlist. I have some additional options on the product view page which are coming from the third party database and i want to display these when customer select such options and add the product to the wishlist. I have already done this when adding a product to the shopping cart. Can somebody help me in this?

Comment: Create an attribute for product. Populate using cron or some script this attribute field. Make sure this attribute when created has proper setting so that its available on product info page. Now in .phtml you use this value and display.

Comment: Options are coming via 3rd party database. We have to add using additional_options

Comment: @user5920 :Did yo find any solution  of it?